# Please replace the [circularsaw] tag with [circular-saw]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tagging

We have some questions tagged [circularsaw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circularsaw). The tag should really be [circular-saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circular-saw) since it's written as two words, not one. We also have several other saw tags that have the hyphen: [band-saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/band-saw), [hand-saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-saw), [hole-saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hole-saw).

Comment: This was bugging me too.

Comment: This was bothering me as well. Good catch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consistency with both the actual terminology of the trade, and with the rest of how the community is tagging similar elements, is always a handy thing to have with a tag system. I've performed the retag for now and instituted a synonym - if we ever want to revisit this, it's easy to reverse, too.

Comment: Ack! We have [tag:tablesaw] too. Should I open another question for that, or can it ride on this one's coattails?

Comment: I would say we probably in the near term want a single meta question with retag requests, which is then updated as they're completed?

Comment: @NiallC. I got it.

Comment: @Joe Here is said meta question: [What needs to be retagged?](http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/63/10)