# Starting out on the right foot

Tags: discussion

Hello fellow woodworkers!

I know we are only a couple hours and less than a hundred questions in, but everything seems to be going very well!

We've [closed our first question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-to-harden-a-steel-chisel-blade), reached [over one hundred users](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/users), and [self-policed our own tag naming system](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/please-replace-the-circularsaw-tag-with-circular-saw).

So far I have been very impressed with the site. But there is one thing that I really want to touch on that has impressed me the most.

**The people here are genuinely being polite, friendly, and warm.**

Just a couple snippets from the comment sections:

> Good point, @saltface. Same goes for drawer bottoms (and for similar reasons). 
>   -[dfife](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/98/what-is-the-proper-place-of-nails-in-woodworking#comment125_102)
>
> I have done this SEVERAL times, although was not ready to admit it. Nice addition @FreeMan
>   -[BrownRedHawk](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-ensure-my-drill-is-perfectly-vertical-before-cutting-a-hole-in-my-desk#comment116_92)
>
> Excellent point about the workpiece being suspended above the table. Something I hadn't considered. -[Doresoom](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/78/is-this-table-saw-lathe-jig-safe#comment111_96)
>
> As long as the answers in the other question apply, you close this as duplicate, it has a pointer to the other one, and you leave a comment explaining that plywood and veneer are pretty similar and the same techniques apply - bingo. -[Joe](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/63/how-can-i-prevent-tearout-of-plywood-when-cutting-it-with-a-circular-saw#comment94_63)

I know it's going to be tough to keep staying courteous and polite as the site gets larger. But the amount of kind words I've seen on this site has impressed me (coming from Stack Overflow). Of course, keep the comments on topic.

Comments, I believe, should be OK spots for nice things to say here. For me, it makes the people on the site feel a little bit more human.

Keep up the good work!

Comment: I've seen this as well and appreciated it. You and I both know overtime as the user base becomes large, things will change. I just hope they change for the better (yes, better than it is now). I like the cordial attitude which is showing a mature audience. I predict great things for the future of this site if it continues on as you have noticed. :D

Comment: Me too! Let's keep the site great and I'm sure great things will come out of it :)

Comment: This is really nice to see. You folks are doing a ***great*** job. Keep up the good work!

Comment: It's nice to read such polite, friendly, and warm comments about how polite, friendly, and warm we are!

Comment: It can stay this way.  I started on Worldbuilding from the private beta and we've all been polite.  As long as we set the tone along these lines it should be able to continue well into the future.

Comment: @Paulster2 `showing a mature audience` Are you trying to say woodworkers are a bunch of old farts?  :)

Comment: @FreeMan - Mature in attitude , but now that you mention it ... :P

Comment: This has been one of the most pleasant private betas I can recall ever being involved in. Thank you all for being great to work with.

Comment: I would have just assumed all private betas would be something like this.

Comment: Honestly, I find Woodworkers to be some of the most amenable to sharing their love of their hobby with others.  We all enjoy a common purpose and are happy to help others along the way.  Keep being awesome, guys!

Comment: Just browsing through the meta questions and stumbled on this one. I just recently joined and from everything I saw all the above statements still stand! I love and enjoy that as well.